# Validating CSV data validity as well as CSV file name before inserting and if there is an error/missing data in between do not insert to database

Tags: php, mysql, validation, csv

I need help on validating CSV data, as well as CSV filename before inserting and if there is an error/missing data in between do not insert to database and print error message.

```
try {
    if(isset($_POST['importSubmit'])){
        //validate whether uploaded file is a csv file
        $csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');
        $surveydate = $_POST['surveydate'];
        $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];

        if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$csvMimes)){
            if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
                //open uploaded csv file with read only mode
                $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

                //skip first line
                fgetcsv($csvFile);

                //parse data from csv file line by line
                while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE) {
                    //check whether member already exists in database with same email
                    //insert member data into database
                    $db->query("INSERT INTO communitysurvey (surveyNum,stationID,age,gender,educationalattainment,question,response,userID,surveydate) VALUES('".$line[0]."', '".$line[1]."','".$line[2]."', '".$line[3]."', '".$line[4]."','".$line[5]."','".$line[6]."','{$userID}','{$surveydate}')");
                }

                //problem on userID session won't get inserted
                //close opened csv file
                fclose($csvFile);      
            }
        }
    }

    //redirect to the listing page
    header("Location: inputcommunity.php".$qstring);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    alert ($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Where in your code do you need help?

Comment: Hi! i need help in coding the data validation that all the data fields in my CSV file are filled and if there is a en empty one or incorrect like for an ID there is a string placed there instead. It will show and error message and will not insert into the database.

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from your CSV you could use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and explode on your delimiters (likely "," or ", " for a CSV) for each line read in in your `while` loop. This will return an array of each value in that line. You can check the length of this array for missing values and compare types/values to expected ones to check for "correctness".